# How to echo an multidimensional array using foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have two variables that contain some data as shown below

```
$main_headings = [Business Structure,Business Management];
```

to make comma separated array i use `explode`

```
$main_headings = explode [',','Business Structure,Business Management'];
```

and second variable contain data like this

```
$sub_headins = [Competitive Positioning, Diversification of Fund Mix, Unit Holding Pattern-Management Quality, Organizational Structure];
```

same i use `explode` with second variable to make array

```
$sub_headins = explode ('-', [Competitive Positioning, Diversification of Fund Mix, Unit Holding Pattern-Management Quality, Organizational Structure];)
```

After this my second variable convert into two arrays

```
array1() = [Competitive Positioning, Diversification of Fund Mix, Unit Holding Pattern];

array2() = [Management Quality, Organizational Structure];
```

now i want my output like this

> - Business Structure
>
>   - Competitive Positioning
>   - Diversification of Fund Mix
>   - Unit Holding Pattern
> - Business Management
>
>   - Management Quality
>   - Organizational Structure

I use for each but i failed to get this output

here is my code

```
foreach ($main_headings as $main_heading) {
    echo $main_heading;
    echo '<br>';
    foreach ($sub_headings as $sub_heading) {
        echo $sub_heading;
         echo '<br>';
    }
}
```

output of my code

> Business Structure Competitive Positioning, Diversification of Fund
>   Mix, Unit Holding Pattern Management Quality, Organizational Structure
>   Business Management Competitive Positioning, Diversification of Fund
>   Mix, Unit Holding Pattern Management Quality, Organizational Structure

Comment: what do you retrieve instead of what do you expected?

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri i update my question with my output

Comment: You first 5 example lines are all syntactically incorrect. That does not help us understand what you have or what you want

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($main_headings as $main_heading) {
    echo "<li>";
    echo $main_heading;
    echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($sub_headings as $sub_heading) {
            echo "<li>";
            echo $sub_heading;
            echo '</li>';
        }
    echo "</ul>";
    echo "</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
foreach ($main_headings as $main_heading) {
    echo '<p>' . $main_heading . '</p>';
    foreach ($sub_headings as $sub_heading) {
        echo '<p style="text-indent=10px;">' . $sub_heading . '</p>';
    }
}
```